# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm building this gem which is currently private but will be open sourced later on.

In the `.gemspec` I have `spec.add_dependency 'hashie', '~> 3.3.2'`.

When using the gem in my app I get:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "hashie":
  In Gemfile:
    desk (~> 1.0.4) ruby depends on
      hashie (~> 2.1) ruby

    my_gem (>= 0) ruby depends on
      hashie (3.3.2)
```

How do I go about solving such issue?

One way is to remove the lock on `~> 3.3.2` which works but I prefer not to do that.

I have tried deleting the `Gemfile.lock` from the app and run `bundle install/update` but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to dependency hell :). It's not possible to use two different versions of the same gem.

You could try to fork desk and update to `hashie ~> 3.3.2` there or simply go with `hashie ~> 2.1` and downgrade your hashie to a 2.x version.

Answer (score 1):

I have accepted @ascar answer because that's the right thing to do. People suggest that you should fork gems to ensure compatibility.

Now what have I done in the spirit of OSS :) I have actually submitted a PR on the Desk gem to update the hashie gem.